# How can I pass custom message to blade from controller?

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this in my blade:

```
<input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>
@error('name')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
@enderror
```

and I would like to pass this through my controller:

```
catch (\Exception $e){
    return back()->withError('name','Somthing Went Wrong Please Try Again!');
}
```

But it does not work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing `$message` you have to print `$name` which you are passing as error

```
@if($errors->has('name'))
  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
  </span>
```

enderror